# Ionic2 upgrade - Uncaught Error: Cannot find module

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

After upgrading to beta.2. My application does not run anymore. I get following error in browser

> Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "..../project/app/app"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just solved with:
`npm install -g ionic@beta`

Remember, there are some breaking changes:
The most important is ionic module change name: from `ionic-framework/ionic` to `ionic-angular`.
Change it in all your .ts files, change it also in `ionic.config.js` file in order to fetch correctly sass files.

Comment: I do keep getting `Cannot find name 'Promise'.` is it same for you?